# Indexing (post) files in solr (8.2.0) docker gives access denied

Tags: docker, solr

Currently running solr(8.2.0) on docker with volume mounted as :
`docker run -p 8883:8983 -d -v $PWD/Resumes:/var/solr/data/Resumes/ solr solr-precreate Resumes`

The data is loading fine and was able to access on browser too.

But when i try to index files by using post tool like :
`docker exec -it <container-id>  post -c Resumes sample-resume.pdf`

I am getting following error:

```
/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java -classpath /opt/solr/dist/solr-core-8.2.0.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=Resumes -Ddata=files org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool sample-resume.pdf
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/Resumes/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file sample-resume.pdf (application/pdf) to [base]/extract
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/Resumes/update...
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #500 (Server Error) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/Resumes/update?commit=true
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":2931},
  "error":{
    "msg":"/var/solr/data/Resumes/data/index/_bau_Lucene80_0.dvm",
    "trace":"java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/solr/data/Resumes/data/index/_bau_Lucene80_0.dvm\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:178)\n\tat java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:292)\n\tat java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:345)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.fsync(IOUtils.java:469)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fsync(FSDirectory.java:331)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.sync(FSDirectory.java:286)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.sync(NRTCachingDirectory.java:158)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.store.LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.sync(LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.startCommit(IndexWriter.java:4804)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3276)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3444)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:3409)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:671)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:102)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1070)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1057)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processCommit(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:160)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerUtils.handleCommit(RequestHandlerUtils.java:69)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:62)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2578)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:780)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:566)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:423)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:350)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\n",
    "code":500}}
Time spent: 0:00:05.542
```

Comment: The docker container (or the user running Solr inside the container) does not have _write access_ to the directory or existing file, so when it tries to append the new content it receives an access denied error.

Comment: How to enable write access in solr container? Are there any additional flags that  i need to add before running container?